# Responsive Header Improvements

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nav

I made a responsive header with left and right floated content and media queries. I know it can be done better, just wanted to see what ideas people have for improving it, while maintaining the general appearance - HTML, CSS, and jQuery - any improvements you have!

https://jsfiddle.net/80mac/5xmnqf7h/#&togetherjs=D4KPRclK3h

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.head').on('click', function(){
  $('.subMenu').toggleClass('open'); 
 }); 
});
```

^just put that there because "a link to jsfiddle.net requires code example"

Thanks

Comment: Looks pretty good to me

Comment: I'd suggest putting this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can try below sample bootstrap responsive menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/84mqazgq/